# What does this star symbol mean in the airport chart?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts, symbology

I know that there is no unidentified beacon because it is not in the circle, because the star symbol inside the circle represents the unidentified beacon. So what does this star symbol mean?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FAA Airport diagram legend](https://www.faasafety.gov/files/gslac/courses/content/573/1781/airport-diagram-legend.pdf) both a 5 point star with and without an enclosing circle both identify a beacon at the airport.

Further details can be found on the FAA website, towards the bottom of [this](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/) page is a link to [Legends & General Information (PDF)](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2210/frntmatter.pdf) where you can find all details of all FAA charts.

Comment: You are right, sir. But when I check out the Jeppesen Legends I do not find any other information than the hazard beacon. It is not possible to have such a thing on the terminal.

Comment: it sure can be. Maybe there's a tall mast or flag pole on the roof with a rotating beacon light on top for example. Think that kind of beacon, not radio beacon.